# Paginate Using Laravel 5 and Propel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, propel

I'm trying to do pagination 6 maximum result to the each page.

**Here is my code in controller:**

```
public function brand_new(Request $request)
    {
$current_page = $request->get('page', 1);
$find_vehicles = $this->filterAll();//retrieving all the vehicles by calling a method
        $total = $find_vehicles->count();
        $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($find_vehicles, $total, 6, $current_page);
        $paginator->setPath($request->getBasePath());
return view('pages.massSearch',compact('paginator'));
```

**Here is my code in *.blade.php:**

```
    @foreach($paginator->getCollection()->all() as $pg)
   {{ $pg->ImagePath }} {{--ImagePath is the php name of a table column--}}
     @endforeach
```

> But I'm getting error :*Trying to get property of non-object*

Any Suggestions will be helpful...

**filterAll method:**

```
public function filterAll($val)
    {
        $filter_avl = VehicleQuery::create()
            ->filterByAvailability(true)
            ->find();
        $filter_modelAvl = VehicleQuery::create()
            ->useVModelQuery()
            ->filterByAvailability(true)
            ->endUse()
            ->find();
        $filter_bndAvl = VehicleQuery::create()
            ->useVBrandQuery()
            ->filterByAvailability(true)
            ->endUse()
            ->find();

        $filter_cStatus = VehicleQuery::create()
            ->useCurrrentStatusQuery()
            ->endUse()
            ->find();
        $filter_mode = VehicleQuery::create()
            ->useVehicleModeQuery()
            ->filterByModeName($val)
            ->endUse()
            ->find();

        $find_vehicles = VehicleImagesQuery::create()
            ->joinWith('VehicleImages.Vehicle')
            ->joinWith('Vehicle.VModel')
            ->joinWith('Vehicle.VBrand')
            ->joinWith('Vehicle.CurrrentStatus')
            ->joinWith('Vehicle.VehicleMode')
            ->filterByVehicle($filter_avl)
            ->filterByVehicle($filter_modelAvl)
            ->filterByVehicle($filter_bndAvl)
            ->filterByVehicle($filter_cStatus)
            ->filterByVehicle($filter_mode)
            ->find();
        return $find_vehicles;
    }//no errors with this code retrieve data perfectly.. Pagination part is the problem.
```

Comment: Please add information on which line causes that error

Comment: Use `@foreach($paginator->getCollection() as $pg)` instead of `@foreach($paginator->getCollection()->all() as $pg)`

Comment: I think form the line  `{{$pg->ImagePath }}`. If I code as `{{ $pg->getImagePath() }}` it gives me error :Call to a member function getImagePath() on array.

Comment: I tried `@foreach($paginator->getCollection() as $pg)` . But giving the save error.

Comment: When I tried `{{ dd($pg) }}` it returns `array:1 [▼
  1790921346 => 0
]`

Comment: What about the parameters that I have passed to the **LengthAwarePaginator** constructor ? Are they fine ??

Comment: can you do `dd($paginator->getCollection())` and tell me what does it returns? use expand all.

Comment: Make sure `$find_vehicles` is an instance of `Collection`

Comment: Can you please give code for `filterAll()` method ?

Comment: It returns all the Objects related to each other. `Collection {#381 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    "␀*␀index" => array:1 [▶]
    "␀*␀indexSplHash" => array:1 [▶]
    "␀*␀model" => "VehicleImages"
    "␀*␀fullyQualifiedModel" => "\VehicleImages"
    "␀*␀formatter" => ObjectFormatter {#}
    "␀*␀data" => array:1 [▼
      0 => VehicleImages {
        #new: false
        #deleted: false
        #modifiedColumns: []
        #virtualColumns: []
        #id: 7
        #image_path: "images/vehicles/audi_a7.jpg"
        #vehicle_id: "XML-4466"
        #aVehicle: Vehicle {#31
        #alreadyInSave: false`

Comment: I can get all the information I need by above query. I prefer to add pagination to  prevent displaying all the vehicles in same page.. But there I found this problem... I couldn't use `*::paginate(6)` because I'm  using **propel orm** instead of  **eloquent** here..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using propel I used **Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB** for this case

```
$find_vehicles = DB::table('vehicle_images')
            ->join('vehicle', 'vehicle_images.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('V_model', function ($join1) {
                $join1->on('vehicle.V_model_id', '=', 'V_model.id')->where('V_model.availability', '=', true);
            })
            ->join('V_brand', function ($join2) {
                $join2->on('vehicle.V_brand_id', '=', 'V_brand.id')->where('V_brand.availability', '=', true);
            })
            ->join('Currrent_status', 'vehicle.Currrent_status_id', '=', 'Currrent_status.id')
            ->join('vehicle_transmission', 'vehicle.vehicle_transmission_id', '=', 'vehicle_transmission.id')
            ->join('vehicle_mode', function ($join3) use($val) {
                $join3->on('vehicle.vehicle_mode_id', '=', 'vehicle_mode.id')->where('vehicle_mode.mode_name', '=',$val);
            })
            ->paginate(6);
```

If any one find a way through with **propel** Please post the answer..Anyway Thank u people, appreciate your help...